# Current Date in SQLAlchemy ORM relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship

I'm trying to configure a relationship between two objects based on the current date. Say I have a `Person` object and a relationship to a bunch of `Event` objects. If the `Event` object holds a `DateTime` (`start`) on it, I want to make a relationship to all of today's events.

So far I have:

```
class Person:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    todays_events = relationship('Event', primaryjoin='and_(Person.id == Event.person_id, cast(Event.start, Date) == "2016-04-23"')
```

This works but I can't find what I need to replace the date string with "2016-04-23" to get the equivalent of `CURDATE()`.

Does anyone know what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the answer right after posting... of course.

`func.current_date()`

so:

```
class Person:
     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     todays_events = relationship('Event', primaryjoin='and_(Person.id == Event.person_id, cast(Event.start, Date) == func.current_date()')
```